# Internet Not Working On Windows 8.1 Partition After Using BootCamp on Mac

Tags: windows, mac, drivers, internet, boot-camp

I partitioned my hard drive and installed Windows 8.1 on my macbook (2011) using BootCamp. Downloaded the drivers automatically by clicking the box in the BootCamp dialog, then manually installed those drivers by going into that drivers folder on the Windows side and using the Setup.exe file. I actually haven't used Windows in quite a while so I'm a little out of my element. Not sure what's wrong but I just can't access the internet on the Windows side and now my computer keeps shutting off when the power is disconnected, even though it claims it's at 99% charge! I suspect this shutoff is somehow related to my partitioning. So my question is, what are my next steps to try to get the internet working in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You can only install Windows 8.1 on Macs running OS X Yosemite, El Cap or macOS Sierra according to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201457). You are also limited to installing it on certain computers, but it appears most Macs from 2011 are supported.

Apple as a company doesn't really like to support older products and unfortunately you can't even try Windows 10 as they don't support machines older than 2012.

If you are running one of the correct macOSes, I'd try to reinstall the Apple-made windows drivers (via USB flash drive copy since your networking isn't working), while booted into Windows 8.1. Barring that, I'd delete the BOOTCAMP partition and try again.